# Need help adding number to dim's in my loop sequence? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Here's basically what I have:

```
Public checkprogresstime_p1 As String = ""
Public checkprogresstime_p2 As String = ""

'P1 Progress bar updater
checkprogresstime_p1 = (time_total.Text - time_p1_hour.Value)
If checkprogresstime_p1 >= 60 Then
    checkprogresstime_p1 = 60
    time_p1_progress.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
ElseIf checkprogresstime_p1 <= 0 Then
    checkprogresstime_p1 = 1
End If
If time_p1_progress.Value < 60 Then
    time_p1_progress.ForeColor = Color.Red
End If
time_p1_progress.Value = checkprogresstime_p1
```

Here's basically what I need:

```
Dim cnt As Integer = 1     

Do
    'P1 Progress bar updater
    checkprogresstime_p(cnt) = (time_total.Text - time_p(cnt)_hour.Value)
    If checkprogresstime_p(cnt) >= 60 Then
        checkprogresstime_p(cnt) = 60
        time_p(cnt)_progress.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
    ElseIf checkprogresstime_p(cnt) <= 0 Then
        checkprogresstime_p(cnt) = 1
    End If
    If time_p(cnt)_progress.Value < 60 Then
        time_p(cnt)_progress.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
    time_p(cnt)_progress.Value = checkprogresstime_p(cnt)
Loop While cnt <= 25
```

I have no idea how to do it... I need it to loop and add +1, 25 times. I basically have it written out 25 times at the moment...

Comment: `For i As Integer = 1 To 25`

Comment: I'm not sure how to use properly that in this situation?

Comment: The thing that does not make sense for me is a progress that only goes to 25? In your Do/Loop you never increment the cnt variable and this means the loop will have an infinite loop. Where a For/Loop is far safer for this.

Comment: Or you could add `cnt += 1` on the line immediately above `Loop While cnt <= 25` to increment the `cnt` variable...

Comment: dim checkprogresstime_p1 as String = ""

I need it to go through all 25 dim's

Comment: @DonA, I don't think you're reading his code correctly. He has 25 progress bars. Each one has a range of 1 to 60. His code is definitely making it look more complicated than it is.

Comment: It pays to explain one's self better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're wanting to do has more to do with having 25 progress bars on your form where each one is named `time_p#_progress` where `#` is the number of the progress bar. That being said, there are two ways to acheive updating your progress bars without having to copy and paste your code 25 times...

### 1. Use `Me.Controls` to get a reference to the progress bar

```
For j = 1 To 25
    Dim pbar As ProgressBar = Me.Controls("time_p" & j & "_progress")
    Dim ph As NumericUpDown = Me.Controls("time_p" & j & "_hour")
    Dim checkprogresstime As Long = (time_total.Text - ph.Value)
    If checkprogresstime >= 60 Then
        checkprogresstime = 60
        pbar.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
    ElseIf checkprogresstime <= 0 Then
        checkprogresstime = 1
    End If
    If time_p1_progress.Value < 60 Then
        pbar.Value = checkprogresstime
    End If
    pbar.Value = checkprogresstime
    Application.DoEvents()
Next
```

Note: You didn't tell us what type of control `time_p1_hour` was. I assumed it was a `NumericUpDown` down control. So, if it's not, you need to replace it the type of control that `time_p1_hour` is.

### 2. Dynamically create your controls as a control array

#### Initizliaze your progress bars in the Form1_Load method (MyBase.Load)

```
Private pbars(24) As ProgressBar

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i = LBound(pbars) To UBound(pbars)
        pbars(i) = New ProgressBar()
        pbars(i).Parent = Me
        pbars(i).Top = i * pbars(i).Height
        pbars(i).Left = 0
        pbars(i).Visible = True
    Next
End Sub
```

#### Put your code inside of a loop like so

```
For cnt = 0 To 24
    checkprogresstime_p(cnt) = (time_total.Text - time_hour(cnt).Value)
    If checkprogresstime_p(cnt) >= 60 Then
        checkprogresstime_p(cnt) = 60
        time_p_progress(cnt).ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
    ElseIf checkprogresstime_p(cnt) <= 0 Then
        checkprogresstime_p(cnt) = 1
    End If
    If time_p_progress(cnt).Value < 60 Then
        time_p_progress(cnt).ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
    time_p_progress(cnt).Value = checkprogresstime_p(cnt)
Next
```

Comment: Ah! Method 1 is close!

checkprogresstime = (time_total.Text - ph.Value)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @teknogeek1300, You need to replace `NumericUpDown` with the type of control that `time_p1_hour` is.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `For/Loop` with your current request. The `cnt` variable will increment itself in this type of `Loop`.

```
For cnt As Integer = 1 To 25
 'P1 Progress bar updater
 checkprogresstime_p(cnt) = (time_total.Text - time_p(cnt)_hour.Value)
 If checkprogresstime_p(cnt) >= 60 Then
    checkprogresstime_p(cnt) = 60
    time_p(cnt)_progress.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
 ElseIf checkprogresstime_p(cnt) <= 0 Then
    checkprogresstime_p(cnt) = 1
 End If
 If time_p(cnt)_progress.Value < 60 Then
    time_p(cnt)_progress.ForeColor = Color.Red
 End If
 time_p(cnt)_progress.Value = checkprogresstime_p(cnt)
Next
```

Comment: I've updated the OP to make more sense. "checkprogresstime_p#" is a dim as string

Comment: That variable is set to an empty string and how does that get filled by data. Also you are doing math with strings? Work on converting types before math.